# PHP load directory select HTML file and send it via Mail

Tags: php, html, email

I set myself to a little `PHP` project. The aim of my project is to create a `webapp` which loads HTML emails from directory and send them out.

The webapp was sending the HTML email files only if they hard coded, but I wanted to create a function that loads all the HTML file from the directory and user can choose which one to send. The function works loaded all the files displays them inside drop down menu but sent emails are blank/empty.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['recipient'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

function LoadTemplate()
    {
    foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/*') as $filename)
        {
        $filename = basename($filename);
        echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>" . $filename . "</option>";
        }

    $message = file_get_contents($filename, "r") or exit("Unable to open file");
    return $message;
    }

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">Send To:
        <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
        <br>Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
        <br>
        <select name="s1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
            <?php require( 'mail.php'); echo LoadTemplate(); ?>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SO I would like to load HTML files from a directory into a drop down menu and then send that file across to addressed person via email so it displays the HTML content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
  <?php


function LoadTemplate()
    {
    foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/*') as $filename)
        {
        echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>" . basename($filename) . "</option>";
        }
    }
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $to = $_POST['recipient'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['s1'], "r") or exit("Unable to open file");
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $mail_send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if($mail_send){
     echo 'Mail Send ';
     }else{
     echo 'Try Later';
     }
}
?>


<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Mail</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">Send To:
        <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
        <br>Subject:
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
        <br>
        <select name="s1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
            <?php require( 'mail.php'); echo LoadTemplate(); ?>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Do ask for help if unable to implement to waste my effort

Comment: Hey thank you for proposed code but when i send an Email nothing is coming through to my inbox

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried it and even though it said _"sent"_ I didn't recieved anything in Gmail or Outlook. Any idea what can cause the problem? Could it be a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want to send the selected static HTML file as the content of your email? That should be an easy task. Your PHP Code does not, what you want it to do. And you source code is having some issues. Let's try to clean it up a little bit:

```
<?php

    // if form was submitted, send the mail
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){ 
        $to = $_POST['recipient'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['s1'], 'r') or exit('Unable to open file');
        $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            $mail_sent = true;
        } else {
            $mail_sent = false;
        }
    } else {
        // read all templates from the folder
        foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/*') as $filename){
            $templates = basename($filename);
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Mail</h2>
        <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) : ?>
            <?php if($mail_sent) : ?>
                <p>The mail has been sent successfully</p>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p>There has been an error sending the mail.</p>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="mail.php">Send To:
            <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient">
            <br>Subject:
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
            <br>
            <select name="s1">
                <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
                <?php foreach($templates as $template) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $template ?>"><?php echo $template ?></option>
                <? endforeach ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep I  agree the code needed some proper cleaning and restructuring but for the purposes of having basics working I coded it in lamest way anyway.......using your changes the email is not sent and erros message is thrown  Unable to open file.....

Comment: looks like the options are not picked up and empty data is inserted

Comment: have you tried to print out the $_POST array? Is the template set.